# Java Automatic Field Value Serialization

Tags: java, serialization, field, bytebuffer

Lets say we have a struct-llike java class

```
public class Person {
    private int height;
    private byte nChildren;
    private int  salary; 

    public byte[] serializeField() {
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 + 1 + 4);
        buf.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        buf.putInt(height);
        buf.put(nChildren);
        buf.putInt(salary);
        return buf.array(); 
    }

    /*
     * setters and getters
     */
}
```

Is there a library that can perform the `serializeField()` function automatically for any given class? It should be able to maintain the *exact order* of the fields as defined in the class and perhaps have the ability to ignore certain fields (like the `serialVersionUID`).

Comment: Isn't this pretty much what you get by marking the class `Serializable` and then writing/reading that object to/from an object stream? Field order is of course maintained, fields can be ignored with `transient`. If you want it to be done exactly like your `serializeField()` function (explicit byte order, no information about the class), then you have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can write one using reflection.

If performance matters, you can

- pass in a ByteBuffer to append to to avoid creating lots of buffers you discard.

  ```
  public void serializeField(ByteBuffer buf) {
      buf.putInt(height);
      buf.put(nChildren);
      buf.putInt(salary);
  }
  ```
- and generate your code (using reflection etc) to avoid using reflection at runtime. i.e. use reflection to generate the code above or in the next example.
- map the fields getters and setters into a ByteBuffer so there is no serialization/deserialization as such.

Say you have an object with a width and height.  As you can see the values are updated into a ByteBuffer (e.g. a direct or memory mapped file)  This way there is no serialization overhead as such.

```
class Sized {
    private ByteBuffer buffer;
    private static final int HEIGHT_OFFSET = 0;
    private static final int WIDTH_OFFSET = 4;

    public void setBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer) {this.buffer = buffer; }
    public int getHeight() { return buffer.getInt(HEIGHT_OFFSET); }
    public void setHeight(int height) { buffer.putInt(HEIGHT_OFFSET, height); }
    public int getWidth() { return buffer.getInt(WIDTH_OFFSET); }
    public void setWidth(int width) { buffer.putInt(WIDTH_OFFSET, width); }
}
```

To handle the memory mapped data you can use a library like this.

https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle

This library allow you to create any number of events/records (billions) which can be updated (but not grown in size once written) very quickly. e.g. millions of records per second with sub-microsecond latency. It can also be shared between processes.  Once you exceed your main memory, the main limitation is the speed of your hard drive if you exceed your memory usage. i.e. an SSD will really help.  It has a mode where you use the Unsafe class directly (more low level than ByteBuffer) by just enabling it.

Comment: I was midway writing one, when it felt like I was reinventing a wheel. Quickly checked out Kryo & others but couldn't get it to do what I needed. I don't seem to understand your first two points. Your last point wouldn't work, because the writing of the buffer will depend on the order in which methods are called. Say setSalary(int) is called before setHeight(int).